# The precise relationship between (moduli space of) finite-dimensional commutative local $\kappa$-algebras and number theory?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, algebraic-number-theory, moduli-spaces

In [BP08] Poonen constructs and studies $\mathfrak{B}_n$, the moduli space of all **based** $n$-dimensional commutative associative unital $\kappa$-algebras, where $\kappa$ is an algebraically closed field of any characteristic. In [BP07] he lists all representatives of the isomorphism types of local such algebras for $n \leq 6$ (depending on $\operatorname{char} \kappa$) (for $n \geq 7$ there are infinitely many isomorphism types).

Moreover, in [BP07] and [BP08] he writes: *"The geometry of this moduli space **seems** to be what is behind the parameterization and enumeration of number ﬁelds of ﬁxed low degree and bounded discriminant, as in the work of Bhargava [Bha04a,Bha04b,Bha04c,Bha05]"* and *"Finally, the moduli
space $\mathfrak{B}_n$ is **implicit** in some of the work of Bhargava [Bha04a, Bha04b, Bha04c, Bha05] on parameterizing and enumerating algebras of rank ≤ 5, especially over $\mathbb{Z}$."*, respectively.

I have a standard ANT background, but I am not a specialist, so it is somewhat difficult to navigate through all four papers of Bhargava to pinpoint and extract the exact relationship. Thus, as non-specialist, I have the following two questions:

1. Given an algebraically closed field $\kappa$ of characteristic $0$, what precisely is the number-theoretic information that $\mathfrak{B}_n$ carries for $n \leq 6$? What is the precise relationship between above classification of local $\kappa$-algebras and the parametrization and enumeration of number fields explicitly?
2. Does $\mathfrak{B}_n$ carry any number-theoretic significance in this context for $n \geq 7$ or does it stop at infinitely many isomorphism types?

**References:**

[BP07] Bjorn Poonen, Isomorphism types of commutative algebras of ﬁnite rank over an algebraically closed ﬁeld, November 16, 2007, AMS Contemporary Math.

[BP08] Bjorn Poonen, The moduli space of commutative algebras of ﬁnite rank, March 8, 2007, J. Europ. Math. Soc.

[Bha04a] Manjul Bhargava, Higher composition laws. I. A new view on Gauss composition, and quadratic generalizations, Ann. of Math. (2) 159 (2004), no. 1, 217–250.

[Bha04b] Higher composition laws. II. On cubic analogues of Gauss composition, Ann. of Math. (2)
159 (2004), no. 2, 865–886.

[Bha04c] Higher composition laws. III. The parametrization of quartic rings, Ann. of Math. (2) 159
(2004), no. 3, 1329–1360.

[Bha05] The density of discriminants of quartic rings and ﬁelds, Ann. of Math. (2) 162 (2005),
no. 2, 1031–1063.